# substitute multiple substrings with per substring substitution

Tags: regex, string, perl, substitution

regarding the following string: *"Do dogs eat cats, or does your cat eat a mouse?"*

I'd like to use the **s///** in Perl to replace each occurrence of "dog" with "cat", "cat" with "mouse" and "mouse" with "dog".

so that the result is: *"Do cats eat mice, or does your mouse eat a dog?"*

My problem is, after the substitution of dogs with cats, cats then appears twice, but I only want to substitute the original cats.

I know I could simply write several substitutions that are not global, but I was wondering if there is a one-liner for that.

ps: of course I want to use the correct plural e.g., “mice” and not “mouses”

Comment: Create a temporal value for changing EG `cat` to `##` and after closing the circle, change `##` to to `mouse`...

Comment: Can you simply split your real input string into token/words? e.g. `split(/\b/,$_)` for the example above. [I have assumed the real problem is "slightly different"]

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip: thanks a lot for your replies, I will use the split approach until but I will soon learn about how to use hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp for finding all matches and hash for finding replacements.
Below please find script constructing regexp from keys of the hash keeping match=>replacement mapping.

Bare bone "proof of concept" version:

```
%S=(dog=>'cat',cat=>'mouse'); # hash with match=>replacements mappings
# substitute "dog" and "cat" for values provided by S hash
s/\b(dog|cat)\b/$S{$1}/g;
# OR if if can easily split input string into "words"
#    substitute "words" present in S hash and keep the rest unchanged
s{\b(\S+?)\b}{$S{$1}//$1}g;
```

Elaborate version with constructing regexp from hash key and tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# %S - hash keeping match=>replacements pairs
my %S = (
  dog  => "cat",
  dogs => "cats",
  cat  => "mouse",
  cats => "mice",
  mouse => "dog",
  mice  => "dogs",
);
my $regex = sprintf '\b(?:%s)\b', join('|',sort keys %S);
$regex = qr($regex);
print "REGEX: ",$regex,"\n"; # print regexp for finding all matches

while( <DATA> ) {
  print "IN:  ",$_; # print string before rewriting
  s/($regex)/$S{$1}/g; # Replace all matches by replacements provided by %S hash
  print "OUT: ",$_; # print string after rewriting
}

# Put your tests strings in lines below __DATA__
__DATA__
Do dogs eat cats, or does your cat eat a mouse?
Does firecat fly?
```

Comment: You don't need the `/e` on the substitution operator here.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot! But I am a little surprised that this simple problem needs such an extensive solution.

Comment: @ic23oluk Raw bone "proof of concept" version: `%S=(dog=>'cat',cat=>'mouse'); s/\b(dog|cat)\b/$S{$1}/g`. Version in the answer is harder to code but easier to maintain - I personally prefer such approach at low cost.